# Django: variable in variable in templates

Tags: python, html, django, templates

Let's assume the following situation. In my database (model) I have a field of description of the task for students. Each student should have their own variant of some variables in the task. So, I save the following model named `task` in the database:

```
 id | name    | description                                  |
 ---+---------+----------------------------------------------+
  1 | Simple  | This is first task. Answer is {{student_var}}|
```

Method for the view is simple (TeamFlag is a table to correlate teams and tasks:

```
def render_team(request, team):
    tasks = TeamFlag.objects.filter(team=team)
    return render(request,
                  'team.html',
                  dict({'team': team,
                        'tasks': tasks,
                        'student_var': 'foo',
                        }))
```

In my template:

```
{% for team_task in tasks %}
    <li class="item">
        <h6>{{ team_task.task.name }}</h6>
        <div class="task-content">{% autoescape off %}
                                  {{team_task.task.description }}
                                  {% endautoescape %}</div>
```

As the result I see:

```
 This is first task. Answer is {{student_var}}
```

Is there any way in Django to pre-process variables, which are inside the string and pass processed HTML string to the view inside the template, basing on variables (I plan to keep variables in database in K-V format in table with fields like: `id`, `key`, `value`, `team_id`, `task_id`).

Generally, I would like to have some method like `process_template(html_string, kv-data)`, which returns processed HTML string or something similar. I heard about custom filters for the templates, but I'm not sure, whether it's the case or not.

UPD: I successfully added the following code:

```
tasks = TeamFlag.objects.filter(team=team)
for tf in tasks:
    data = TaskData.objects.filter(team=team, task=tf.task)
    tf.task.description = Template(tf.task.description).render(
        Context(dict(zip([x.key for x in data],
                         [x.value for x in data]))))
```

However, Django now ignores layout in `tf.task.description`. My new description looks like:

`I have some {{temp}} <b>here</b> and it's {{temp2}}`

It's being rendered, I can see it in source code of the page, but actually nothing happens.

UPD2: Seems to be CSS problem. Question closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a helper method, you could create something with `Template` and `Context`

```
from django.template import Template, Context

def process_template(tasks, student_var):
    new_tasks = []
    for team_task in tasks:
        template = Template(team_task.task.description)
        context = Context({'student_var': student_var})
        rendered_template = template.render(context)
        team_task.task.description = rendered_template
        new_tasks.append(team_task)
    return new_tasks

def render_team(request, team):
    tasks = process_template(TeamFlag.objects.filter(team=team))
```

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) for more info.

Comment: I updated fields in models, but not saved them, so there've not been any change in database, though updated models were properly passed to the template: 
`for tf in tasks:
      template = Template(tf.task.description)
      context = Context({'temp': '123'})
      tf.task.description = template.render(context)`

Answer (score 1):

The template processor is just code. It accepts a string, parses it, and populates it according to the context it is given. The string can just as easily come from the database as from a file on disk.

At its root it is as simple as:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

tpl = Template(task.description)
output = tpl.render(tpl, Context({'student_var': 'foo'}))
```

Where you put this is up to you. It could be a model method, or a template filter. One question you don't answer is where the variables are coming from; if there is only `student_var`, you can pass that in to the filter explicitly; if not you'll have to work out where to get them from.

Comment: All `student_var`-like variables will come from database and corresponding model. What about the string, which comes from model as well? I need just to put it into `Context` as well?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What string?

Comment: `task.description` string

Comment: But haven't I shown that in the answer? You pass that into the Template instantiation, it's not part of the context.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it and report my results. I just don't want to do rendering on my own

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple tag and use that in django template like below:

{% my_custom_filter team_task.task.description %}

```
from django.template import Context, Template

@register.simple_tag(name='my_custom_filter', takes_context=True)
def my_custom_filter(context, val):
    template = Template(val)
    context = Context(context)
    final_val = template.render(context)
    return final_val
```